# Do I need ITIN as Japanese citizen to get my deposited money back?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, itin

I am Japanese girl. 
I was a student in US and have deposited some money in bank account.
I am back to Japan now.
I am filing the W-8BEN. 
Do I need to submit the following to get my full money back ?

1. ITIN
2. Foreign tax identifying number

I don't have any of thesis, what do I do?

EDIT:  Actually since I came back to Japan, my account was closed after sometime and now the money is under the custody of US govt and not the bank.

Comment: What did you use to open the bank account when you were in the United States?

Comment: Actually since I came back to Japan, my account was closed after sometime and now the money is under the custody of US govt and not the bank.

Comment: Probably not US govt. More likely State govt.

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide evidence that you are the person who opened the account (which may be as simple as providing your signature, since this isn't really different from asking for a bank check or inter-bank transfer or ATM-network transfer), there should be no problem.

Contact your bank and ask *them* what information they need to provide.

Comment: Actually since I came back to Japan, my account was closed after sometime and now the money is under the custody of US govt and not the bank.

Comment: That's actually handled by the state in most cases. Since it _is_ state by state, you need to contact the state agencies which handle this. There are websites for most of them; searching for "abandoned funds" will find them. If you don't find it, most states have .gov websites where you can look for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The line you are referring to says

> 5 U.S. taxpayer identification number (SSN or ITIN), if required (see
>   instructions)

It does not appear to be required in your case.